# ¿Cual es la razon de ser de saved id en UNIX?

Tags: unix, proceso

No se cual es la diferencia

Estoy aprendiendo con este [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHu7qI1gDPA&t=659s), exactamente de lo que estoy preguntando se empieza a hablar en el minuto **35:12**.

- **real id:** Es el usuario que inicio el proceso, segun he entendido
- **effective id:** Es el usuario que determina los privilegios
- **saved id:** la llamada al sistema exec inicializa este id de usuario de
  manera que este valor es igual al de effective id

No se muy bien como es lo del saved id, hasta donde he entendido es como tener el effective id repetido dos veces. ¿En que se diferencia saved id del effective id de un proceso en cuestión?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X lo que veo x ahí, el saved user id (`suid`)se utiliza cuando un programa con altos privilegios necesita hacer acciones que requieren privilegios más bajos. En ese caso se guarda el effective user id (`euid`) en el `suid` para poder volver a setear el `euid` al valor original más adelante. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier